# Exe not displaying Setting User defined values in Different system in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

There are different libraries used in my main project. In one of them there are some values defined, for e.g

```
m_portnumber = My.Settings.PortNumber
```

In the My.Settings file `PortNumber = 8` and the scope is `User`. After building the solution, when I ran the application (.exe) in my system, `port number = 8` is displaying in UI and working fine.

But the same exe when I run in other systems, the port number values are blank. What can be the reason for this??

Comment: Does the other user have the settings file? Where is the settings file stored?

Comment: The main project exe contains all the supportive dll. Portnumber is defined in one of the library & inside that library in app.config file details are there . After building the main project , only dll of that library say PortCollectionlib.dll is given to release folder.

Comment: Actually i have merged some new code into that library , &  made changes in Settings.Designer.vb & resource file.Before merging everything was working fine . Now it is not displaying value in other pc.

Comment: Can't you just check it's value when the application starts, and if it's blank just set it to the default value? Also, what is the type of the property (String, Integer, etc.)?

Comment: @Vincent ..when application starts ,in app.config  default value is present & it works fine.But in different system we are providing exe of main startup project & supporting dll, where it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved as it was due to one library that was build in debug mode , once we build the library (supporting dll used in project)in release mode , exe of application was working fine on every system.